# Date Ticks or String ticks as xAxis for line chart in d3

Tags: string, d3.js

Is that possible to pass String or date values for xAxis in line chart using d3 charts?=

Answer (score 2):

You can use dates for axes as described [here](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Axes#wiki-ticks) and in particular [here](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Scales#wiki-ticks). See also the documentation for [`tickFormat`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Axes#wiki-tickFormat). Using this you should be able to display arbitrary strings as well.